# Why is my inner JS function not executed? Closures scope

Tags: javascript

I am learning about closures in JS

```
function greetCustomer() {
  const customerName = "anchal";
  function greetingMsg() {
    console.log("Hi! " + customerName);
    function gBrzi(){
        const bName = "brzi"
        console.log("Hello "+ bName) 
    } 
    return gBrzi; 
  }
  return greetingMsg;
}

const callGreetCustomer = greetCustomer();
callGreetCustomer();
```

When I run code node mycode.js, I got

```
Hi! anchal
```

When I run my code in REPL

```
> callGreetCustomer();
Hi! anchal
[Function: gBrzi]
> console.dir(callGreetCustomer);
[Function: greetingMsg]
```

It seems that I do not understand closures. Why is my most inner function gBrzi not executed?

Comment: return gBrzi() instead of return gBrzi will run the inner function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function greetCustomer() {
  const customerName = "anchal";
  function greetingMsg() {
    console.log("Hi! " + customerName);
    function gBrzi(){
        const bName = "brzi"
        console.log("Hello "+ bName) 
    } 
    return gBrzi(); 
  }
  return greetingMsg;
}

const callGreetCustomer = greetCustomer();
callGreetCustomer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retuening a variable

```
return gBrzi;
```

you should call the function and return its return value (that was also missing).

```
function greetCustomer() {
  const customerName = "anchal";
  function greetingMsg() {
    console.log("Hi! " + customerName);
    function gBrzi(){
        const bName = "brzi"
        console.log("Hello "+ bName) 
        return(bName);
    } 
    return gBrzi(); 
  }
  return greetingMsg;
}
```

changes compared to your code:

- added "return(bName);"
- added "()" in "return gBrzi();"

Answer (score 1):

```js
function gBrzi(){
        const bName = "brzi";
        console.log("Hello "+ bName); 
    } 
function greetingMsg(customerName) {
    console.log("Hi! " + customerName);
    gBrzi();
  }
function greetCustomer() {
  const customerName = "anchal";
  greetingMsg(customerName);
}

greetCustomer();
```